# Debian and Win 8.1 Dual Boot (Separate HDD)

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, debian, multi-boot

Im trying to install Debian on my new laptop. I have a 128GB SSD and 1TB HDD. Windows is on the SSD, and i want to install debian on the other drive. My problem is, when i install debian, i put the GRUB loader on the 1TB HDD, doesn't work. I made a research and i found that i can install the GRUB loader on the windows SSD. It did't work too.

When i finish the Debian instalation it always boot by default on windows. Also i've tried to change the boot order of the disks, but not seems to work.

My question is, what is the real procedure or what can i do to boot both OS on my laptop?. For me is not a problem to select every time what disk to boot(if ther's a way to make it work).

Thanks you! :)

Comment: Did installation mention "UEFI"?  With recent BIOSes the boot phase became much more complicated thanks to UEFI. All in all, I'd try the just issued first release candidate of the upcoming "Jessie" (the next Debian release): https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/ -- it should have many improvements in the UEFI field.

Comment: Indeed, i realized later all that UEFI stuff, i successfully installed Debian but then i came across with nvidia driver issues, i think i will try with the newest version of Debian. And thanks for the link !